# Limit on number of memcached buckets in CouchBase?

Tags: memcached, couchbase

This page - http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/Misc/limits.html mentions 'Max Buckets per Cluster - Default is 10 (can be adjusted by users)'. It is not clear whether that is combined limit for both couchbase and memcached buckets or it only applies to couchbase buckets.

I am interested in knowing if there are any limits on the number of memcached buckets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't formally test the limits for memcached buckets, but the overhead of each memcached bucket is relatively low in the data layer (the management and cluster layer consumes more resources and will most likely be your limiting factor). I ran a quick test on my laptop this morning and I could easily create 50 + buckets and the data storage layer consumed < 1% CPU in an idle state (and the cluster and management layer consumed 36%). The overhead during normal client operation is relatively small and occur when the client connects and it needs to look up the credentials and the internal bucket in a pool of n items instead of max 10 items.

People typically deploy Couchbase buckets over memcached buckets due to replication, indexes, persistence, N1QL etc and all of this functionality consumes resources.

It is also very hard define such limits because the hardware will of course count just as much :-)

Oh, And I don't know how the cluster UI behaves with a high number of buckets given that all our formal testing is within the 10 bucket limit.